# Wordpress Themes Directory: Template which hits the standards?

Tags: theme-development, themes

Is there a template which I can use for themes which I want to submit to the wordpress themes directory? A naked template which hits the standards of the Wordpress Themes Directory and which I could use as base for developping new themes would be great. Is there maybe an official "naked" theme which can be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for standards, you want to make sure you look at TwentyTen and TwentyEleven - those are included with Wordpress and written by the core developers.

It doesn't get anymore "standard" :-)

But in terms of guidelines - this is the best place to look for official rules:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Frameworks are there to help speed things up and get your project done. But none of theme will cover all of your needs.

Try a few out - see if one works for you. If not then just grab the [html5boiler](http://html5boilerplate.com/) plate and start from there.

Comment: The point is that I'd like to create some themes for the wp themes directory. In the past I had some problems to get my themes into the directory because they didn't "hit" the "standards". So I hoped that there is something which I could use as a model so I could concentrate at the design without thinking about any other things which a theme for the wp themes directory must have.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a Framework.

Here are a couple of good ones:

["Hybrid"](http://themehybrid.com/hybrid-core)

["Thematic"](http://themeshaper.com/thematic/)

If you are looking for something a bit simpler check out this post:
http://speckyboy.com/2010/03/22/10-blanknaked-wordpress-themes-perfect-for-development/